# stop enumitem \item breaking across pages

Tags: page-breaking, enumitem

A colleague asked this.

Can you automatically demand that items in an enumitem custom list should not spread across a page break? Say this is for an exam where it is preferred that each question is displayed all together, and that questions are not longer than a page.

A simple version of the original context is below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % needed by blindtext
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext} % to produce dummy text only
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[questions,1]{label*=\textbf{\arabic*}.}
\setlist[questions,2]{label=(\alph{questionsii})}
\setlist[questions,3]{label=(\roman{questionsiii})}

\begin{document}
    ~\vspace{15cm} % to push the text near the page break
    
    \begin{questions}
        \item \Blindtext[1][4]
        \item \Blindtext[2][4]
        \begin{questions}
            \item \Blindtext[1][4]
            \item \Blindtext[1][4]
            \item \Blindtext[1][4]
        \end{questions}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I have a couple of ideas, which I'll post here as answers because (a) he said his searching on this question hadn't led him to anything he could get working; (b) I'm interested in other solutions to the problem that might be better.

Comment: I don't know about automatic handling of your formatting objective. To do it manually, one could load the `needspace` package and issue the instruction `Needspace{6\baselineskip}` right before `\item \Blindtext[2][4]`. That said, I can't see what's supposed to be so objectionable about a mid-paragraph page break.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. With `needspace` though I'd need to know how many lines my question item was going to be, which feels like quite a lot of additional hassle.

The context is something like an exam where there might be 4-6 questions and each question might take up a third to a half of a page and it's considered clearer for students (who might be extremely stressed by the exam) to keep all parts of a single question on the same page.

Answer (score 6):

This should work in most cases. We set `\interlinepenalty=10000` in the `questions` environment and also add `\nobreak` after `\par`; since `\item` issues a penalty, a break will be possible between items.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % needed by blindtext
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext} % to produce dummy text only
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[questions,1]{label*=\textbf{\arabic*}.}
\setlist[questions,2]{label=(\alph{questionsii})}
\setlist[questions,3]{label=(\roman{questionsiii})}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{env/questions/begin}{%
  \ifnum\enitdp@questions=0
    \interlinepenalty=10000
    \AddToHook{para/after}[nobreak]{\nobreak}%
  \fi
}
\AddToHook{env/questions/end}{%
  \ifnum\enitdp@questions=1
    \RemoveFromHook{para/after}[nobreak]%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\vspace*{15cm} % to push the text near the page break
    
    \begin{questions}
        \item \Blindtext[1][4]
        \item \Blindtext[2][4]
        \begin{questions}
            \item \Blindtext[1][4]
            \item \Blindtext[1][4]
            \item \Blindtext[1][4]
        \end{questions}
    \end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Due to the possibility of nesting `questions` we want to add to the hooks just once, so we do it when the depth counter is zero (as it is at the moment `env/questions/begin` is looked at. The removal of the `\nobreak` is done only when the depth counter is one, that is, at the `\end{questions}` for the outer level.

[image]

Comment: Is `\AddToHook` local? I never knew.

Comment: @gusbrs Oops. Really fixed now.

Comment: You had made me go "Wow, new possibilities!" :-)

Comment: Thanks, that's really interesting and looks good because it completely preserves the use of `\begin{questions}`. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "This should work in most cases"? Are you aware of edge cases where it doesn't, or just concerned such an edge case might exist?

Comment: @PeterRowlett More testing should be done with real documents in order to lift the doubt.

Answer (score 1):

To get a block of text to not break across pages you can put it inside a `\begin{minipage}...\end{minipage}` environment. A few ways I can think to do this. All these produce the same result, the difference is in the implementation. I think I prefer option 2, which is more complicated in the preamble but seems to me simpler to use.

**1. Putting each item in its own minipage.**

Basically, you need to do this, and can do so manually:

```
\begin{questions}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \item question text
    \end{minipage}
\end{questions}
```

This is perhaps a bit of a faff to remember, so you could define a new command to do this for you. This could be done either as an environment or as a command, though note both would change the usual practice of using `\item text` because a minipage has a beginning and an end, whereas `\item` just has a beginning.

*1a. As an environment.*

We define an environment called `nobreakitem` in the premble. This environment is used instead of the `\item` command. The two line breaks before `\begin{minipage}` are necessary because otherwise it thinks the `minipage` is part of the previous `\item` and doesn't put a line break between them. It could be just used for a problematic `\item`, or for all `\item`s. This, to me, is a bit weird because you are doing `\begin` and `\end` instead of the usual `\item` and it's not saving much vs. writing the above code yourself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % needed by blindtext
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext} % to produce dummy text only
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[questions,1]{label*=\textbf{\arabic*}.}
\setlist[questions,2]{label=(\alph{questionsii})}
\setlist[questions,3]{label=(\roman{questionsiii})}

\newenvironment{nobreakitem}{
    
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\item}{\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
    ~\vspace{15cm} % to push the text near the page break
    
    \begin{questions}
        \begin{nobreakitem}
            \Blindtext[1][4]
        \end{nobreakitem}
        \begin{nobreakitem}
            \Blindtext[2][4]
            \begin{questions}
                \item \Blindtext[1][4]
                \item \Blindtext[1][4]
                \item \Blindtext[1][4]
            \end{questions}
        \end{nobreakitem}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

*1b. As a command.*

We define a command called `\nobreakitem` in the premble. The standard `\item` just applies to whatever comes after it, but here we need to tell it where to put the `\end{minipage}`, so we must enclose what comes after with `{}` and pass this to our command, which is an unfortunate change over `\item`. Again, the line breaks in the `\newcommand` definition are needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % needed by blindtext
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext} % to produce dummy text only
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[questions,1]{label*=\textbf{\arabic*}.}
\setlist[questions,2]{label=(\alph{questionsii})}
\setlist[questions,3]{label=(\roman{questionsiii})}

\newcommand{\nobreakitem}[1]{
    
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\item #1\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
    ~\vspace{15cm} % to push the text near the page break
    
    \begin{questions}
        \nobreakitem{\Blindtext[1][4]}
        \nobreakitem{\Blindtext[2][4]
        \begin{questions}
            \item \Blindtext[1][4]
            \item \Blindtext[1][4]
            \item \Blindtext[1][4]
        \end{questions}}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

**2. An alternative that preserves the usual approach to using `\item`**

To preserve the use of `\item` in the usual way within questions, we can use a feature of `enumitem` where a list can resume a previous list. Here each `\begin{question}` is its own instance of `\begin{questions}` wrapped inside a `minipage`, but numbered as a continuation of the global set of questions. Each `\begin{question}` should contain only one top-level `\item`, but it can contain sub-parts (defined in the usual way via `\begin{questions}`). Then each top-level question and its sub-parts won't break across pages.

The `\ifthenelse` is used because the continuation counting in `enumitem` requires a different command to be used for the first list than subsequent ones, and I wanted the user to avoid having to think about this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % needed by blindtext
\usepackage[pangram]{blindtext} % to produce dummy text only
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[questions,1]{label*=\textbf{\arabic*}.}
\setlist[questions,2]{label=(\alph{questionsii})}
\setlist[questions,3]{label=(\roman{questionsiii})}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\gdef\questionsstarted{0}
\newenvironment{question}{\ifthenelse{\equal{\questionsstarted}{0}}{\gdef\questionsstarted{1}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\begin{questions}[series=questions,start=1,leftmargin=*,resume]}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\begin{questions}[resume*=questions]}}{\end{questions}\end{minipage}\bigskip}

\begin{document}
    ~\vspace{15cm} % to push the text near the page break
    
    \begin{question}
        \item \Blindtext[1][4]
    \end{question}

    \begin{question}
        \item \Blindtext[2][4]
        \begin{questions}
            \item \Blindtext[1][4]
            \item \Blindtext[1][4]
            \item \Blindtext[1][4]
        \end{questions}
    \end{question}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Provided each item is within a local group, `\interlinepenalty=10000` within that same group should do what you want.